# Existe significado na expressão "ir de mota"?

Tags: português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas

Eu tenho a sensação que já ouvi a expressão "ir de mota" ou "vou de mota". Não no sentido literal em que a pessoa usa uma mota para se deslocar, mas sim no sentido de ir rápido e sem preocupações ou obstáculos.

Há alguma fonte oficial que corrobore este significado e que tenha esta expressão?

Segundo o priberam "mota" é uma redução de motocicleta e creio que é assim entendida no português europeu.

https://dicionario.priberam.org/mota

> mo·ta |ó|2 (redução de motocicleta) nome feminino
>
> 1. [Portugal]  Veículo de duas rodas accionado por um motor = MOTO
>
> "mota", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/mota.

Comment: Não seria uma metáfora? De acordo com TodaMatéria: "A metáfora representa uma comparação de palavras com significados diferentes e cujo termo comparativo fica subentendido na frase". Fui de mota para o mercado (fui como uma mota para o mercado).

Comment: @Schilive Talvez? Não sei se será uma metáfora, ou uma expressão idiomatica, ou ambas...

Comment: Sim, mota é a palavra comum para um motociclo em Portugal.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, Bruno!

À princípio, pensei que houvesse um erro de digitação e que quisesse escrever "moto" ou um diminutivo de motocicleta. Pra tirar minha dúvida, fui atrás de saber o significado dessa gíria e acho que a mais se encaixa em sua pergunta é que "mota é gíria para canhâmo ou maconha".

https://www.achando.info/mota

Comment: Ver a pergunta novamente. Eu editei o significado de mota na pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre [tag:português-europeu]. Esta resposta não é adequada, porque "maconha" é uma palavra exclusiva de português-brasileiro.

Comment: Maconha = cannabis, marihuana, marijuana. No Brasil também falamos "beck", baseado entre outros.